# Google Backup&Sync and Photos - double quota hit?

Tags: backup, synchronization, google-drive, google-photos

I switched from using Google Drive+Photos Uploader to Google Backup&Sync.

I select my photos folder to sync, and also select to upload photos to Google Photos as well.

Now in Google Drive I have content under the "Computers" tab, which is my photos folder.

However, in my quota, it appears a lot of photos are now counted against my Google Drive quota. When I click on the Drive icon in the Quota pop-up, it shows me a list of photos seemingly chewing up Drive space. However all these photos also appear in Google Photos.

Are photos counted twice against my quota when I upload them to Computers and Photos using Backup&Sync? I no longer have an option to just upload to Photos as I did with Google Photos Uploader.

Answer (score 1):

They're only counted once. If you choose to upload original files, they will use your drive quota, while "High Quality" (re compressed by Google) photos don't use quota. Both could appear in Drive and Photos.

Comment: Are you sure just once? Please see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127580/do-google-photos-images-take-up-quota-when-appearing-in-google-drives-google-p

Answer (score 0):

As the photo size quality mentioned by Chang Qian, you can learn more about it here https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791
BTW, it is said that since the merge of Google Photos and Google Drive, users will no longer enjoy unlimited storage for photos. There is no final conclusion whether it is true or not.